# Fill an array at index n with m times data without bit-fields

Tags: c, arrays, bit-fields

I try to send a maximum of 8 bytes of data. The first 4 bytes are always the same and involve defined commands and an address. The last 4 bytes should be variable.

So far I'm using this approach. Unfortunatly I was told to not use any for loops in this case.

```
// Construct data
local_transmit_buffer[0] = EEPROM_CMD_WREN;
local_transmit_buffer[1] = EEPROM_CMD_WRITE;
local_transmit_buffer[2] = High(MSQ_Buffer.address);
local_transmit_buffer[3] = Low(MSQ_Buffer.address);

uint_fast8_t i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < MSQ_Buffer.byte_lenght || i < 4; i++){ // assign data
    local_transmit_buffer[i + 4] = MSQ_Buffer.dataPointer[i];
}
```

This is some test code I'm trying to solve my problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>

__UINT_FAST8_TYPE__ local_transmit_buffer[8];
__UINT_FAST8_TYPE__ MSQ_Buffer_data[8];


void print_local(){
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", local_transmit_buffer[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void print_msg(){
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", MSQ_Buffer_data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(){
    // assign all local values to 0
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        local_transmit_buffer[i] = 0;
    } print_local();

    // assign all msg values to 1
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        MSQ_Buffer_data[i] = i + 1;
    } print_msg();

    *(local_transmit_buffer + 3) = (__UINT_FAST32_TYPE__)MSQ_Buffer_data;

    printf("\n");
    print_local();

    return 0;
}
```

The first loops fills up the local_transmit_buffer with 0's and the MSQ_Buffer with 0,1,2,...
local_transmit_buffer -> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
MSQ_Buffer_data       -> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

Now i want to assign the first 4 values of MSQ_Buffer_data to local_transmit_buffer like this:
local_transmit_buffer -> 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4

Is there another way of solving this problem without using for loops or a bit_field?

**Solved:**
I used the memcpy function to solve my problem

```
// uint_fast8_t i = 0;
// for(i = 0; i < MSQ_Buffer.byte_lenght || i < 4; i++){ // assign data
//     local_transmit_buffer[i + 4] = MSQ_Buffer.dataPointer[i];
// } 

// copy a defined number data from the message to the local buffer to send
memcpy(&local_transmit_buffer[4], &MSQ_Buffer.dataPointer, local_save_data_length);
```

Comment: Did you look at memcpy() function?

Comment: By the way, your printing functions won't seem to work, no matter what data you have in your buffers. You could also simplify it by using a single function to print from both buffers, by passing a pointer to the first element as argument (and the size too preferably).

Comment: Why without bitfields though? This sounds like _made_ for bitfields. `struct { uint64_t cmd1 : 8, cmd2: 8, addr : 16, data : 32; } buffer;` But I mean, you can always just unroll the loops since the amount of iterations is constant...

Comment: @Siguza Perfect way to trash up straight-forward EEPROM programming with endianess, aliasing and alignment bugs. And that just 3 reasons out of many why we don't use bit-fields. And I'm curious to know which 64 bit computer that comes with on-chip EEPROM.

Comment: @OldProgrammer memcpy is exactly what i searched for! Thanks. I just need to know how i increment my pointer by 3. So far i am having this:
memcpy(&local_transmit_buffer + 3, &MSQ_Buffer_data, 4);
But it only prints zeros.

Edit: nvm Got it! memcpy(&local_transmit_buffer[4], &MSQ_Buffer_data, 4);
Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can't use `memcpy` like this together with `uint_fast8_t`, or there is not a reason to use `uint_fast8_t` in the first place. You'd need to copy `4*sizeof(uint_fast8_t)` bytes. But in this case, it is plain wrong to use  `uint_fast8_t` since this is data used for NVM programming. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

- Either just unroll the loop manually by typing out each line, or simply use `memcpy`. In this case there's no reason why you need abstraction layers, so I'd write the sanest possible code, which is just manual unrolling (and get rid of icky macros):

  ```
  uint8_t local_transmit_buffer [8];
  ...
  local_transmit_buffer[0] = EEPROM_CMD_WREN;
  local_transmit_buffer[1] = EEPROM_CMD_WRITE;
  local_transmit_buffer[2] = (uint8_t) ((MSQ_Buffer.address >> 8) & 0xFFu);
  local_transmit_buffer[3] = (uint8_t) (MSQ_Buffer.address & 0xFFu);
  local_transmit_buffer[4] = MSQ_Buffer.dataPointer[0];
  local_transmit_buffer[5] = MSQ_Buffer.dataPointer[1];
  local_transmit_buffer[6] = MSQ_Buffer.dataPointer[2];
  local_transmit_buffer[7] = MSQ_Buffer.dataPointer[3];
  ```
- It is not obvious why you can't use a loop though, this doesn't look like the actual EEPROM programming (where overhead code might cause hiccups), but just preparations for it. Start to question such requirements.
- Also note that you should *not* use `__UINT_FAST8_TYPE__` but `uint8_t`. Never use homebrewed types but always `stdint.h`. But you should not be using `fast` types for a RAM buffer used for EEPROM programming, because it cannot be allowed to contain padding, ever. This is a bug.